# How to update the container settings in Azure App Services through REST API?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm using Azure App Services with Docker Compose support enabled. I'm using both DockerHub and Azure Container Registry for my project. I'm looking for Azure App Service REST API that can update the details in the container settings in App Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the SDK [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites) with the code or use the [`API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. I would like to go with REST API. Can we update the container setting details in "Web Apps - Update Application Settings", right?

Comment: even though i have not tried, you should be able to

Comment: I didn't get the container details from the application settings. I'm looking similar like this in REST API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-container-set